# Is this a proper way to implement SSL Sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, serversocket

I am trying to implement secured Socket connections between a Spring Server and an Android Client but I found some design problems.

At the beginning I implemented the solution provided in [this tutorial](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Socket_SSL_con_Java) (it's in Spanish but easily understandable with Google Traductor). This tutorial secures Socket connections with a key in each side (one for server and one for client) and uses a ***trustedKeys.jks*** to store trusted keys in each side. 
That means that for every client I should:

1. Create a new keystore for each new client
2. Add this new client key to trusted keys on server side
3. Add server keystore to each new client

This seemed unrealistic to me considering the growth of the number of clients.

I found another approach that suits better my requirements, it uses the server certificate as a public key (I think) and ciphers the data with it, that will be deciphered by the server keystore:

#### Server Code

```
public SSLServerSocket getSSLServerSocket(int port) throws IOException, ...
{
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(resourceKeyFile.getInputStream(), keystorePassword.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keystore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
        return (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(port);
}
```

Here is my function for creating a SSLServerSocket. In the KeyManagerFactory initialization `kmf.init(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());` I set the server keystore `keystore` with its password `keystorePassword` which are read with `@Value` Spring Annotation outside the function. This function will return the SSLServerSocket which will accept client connections in a new Thread like this:

```
    while(true) {
        SSLSocket clientSocket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
    }
```

#### Client code

```
    SSLContext context = socketUtil.createSSLContext(); 
    SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();

    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(serverUrl, port);
```

This code creates the context I want to usem which is presented below, and creates the Socket to an address `serverUrl` and a port `port`:

```
public final SSLContext createSSLContext()
            throws Exception {

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("serverCert.pem");
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(null);
        try {
            X509Certificate cacert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
            trustStore.setCertificateEntry("serverKey", cacert);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        return sslContext;
    }
```

Here, I load the Server certificate `serverCert.pem` which I generated from the keystore with the `keytool` utility. Then other parameters are setted, such as the algorithm or the protocol. Thus, the socket will trust connections from the issuer of the certificate.

The code is working just nice and smooth, but I'm concerned about security and good practices. So once again, **is this a good approach to solve my problem?**

Any clarifications about the process, code or misunderstandings are welcome. Thank you so much!

Comment: "it uses the server certificate as a public key (I think) and ciphers the data with it, that will be deciphered by the server keystore" You shouldn't use asymmetric cryptography to encrypt large chunks of data as [it is insecure for data bigger than the key size](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/why-is-asymmetric-cryptography-bad-for-huge-data). Also your two methods differ substantially: the first method is able to authenticate the clients are legitimate while you lose that ability with the second method where any client is trusted.

Comment: Is your Spring server hosted on a Tomcat or other application server ? If so, you just need to activate an SSL host, and write client code (the one you gave is OK, it looks like the one given in the JSSE Reference Guide).

Comment: Hi @m0skit0 thank you for your fast answer! So if asymmetric crypto is not the best approach, what other solution you think is the best one? Although, authentication is not a problem in this case because I'm using a SSO (Keycloak) to authenticate users through JWT and every request will contain this token which identifies the user.

Comment: I'm not sure about your comment if you implemented that asymmetric encryption by yourself or you were referring to SSL. If you were referring to SSL, then it should be ok (but note that SSL does not encrypt data using asymmetric but symmetric crypto).

Comment: No I haven't implemented asymmetric encryption by myself, it was just a guess. All the SSL encryption I do is in the shown code. So it should be symmetric. I've maid time measurements and with encryption time grew up to 7-8 times the original time. I don't know if this is an acceptable difference. Thanks anyway!